# what is the best identifier when caching Sets ? When happens hashCode calculation of a Set?

Tags: java, caching, set, hashcode

What is the best way to implement a cache for Sets? Particularly, what makes the best key for the cache?

In a static factory method, I want to include a caching mechanism, so that I can reuse existing (immutable) objects. This reuse should not come with a significant performance penalty. The critical data of this class is a parametrized LinkedHashSet. I'm wondering if it's wise to use the hashCode of this Set as key for the cache (HashMap), because in the java documentation it says:
"The hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set".
Isn't this potentially a slow process? When is it calculated? As soon as the Set is generated or on demand? Couldn't this actually eat up lots the performance gains I expect to gain by caching?

Furthermore, hashCode is an int, but HashMaps don't accept primitives, so this involes boxing to Integer, right?

My current approach, would be to maintain an additional set of the lengthes of sets of the existing objects. The factory method would first check if the current set's lenght is listed, only then looks up in the actual index. But this also involves boxing...

Is there a better solution?

Comment: the hashCode for a set depends on its contents. For a cache, you usually have a key that identifies the data that the set represents (like "admin-memberids"), and the contents (and hashCode) could change over time.

Comment: thanks thilo. Assuming the keySet is final and doesn't change, then the hashCode of the Set is my only reasonable choice to identify the set right?

Comment: You could use the set itself as key (this avoids collisions).

Comment: @paulo: what would happen under the hood if I used the set as key? wouldn't that save the only reference of that set? If then I'd look up with a semantically identical other set, the cache would match or not? Not sure, but I believe it would not

Comment: If you use the Set itself as a key, then the cache would be pretty much useless (you need the data that you want from the cache in order to use the cache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some invariant as the key for each set, something that logically defines the contents of that set.

Consider creating a `NamedSet` either wrapping your existing set implementation with a simple Delegator, or subclassing it (if it is not final). Then you can provide an additional key or name field to identify the set and use that as the key for your cache.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it's hard to find an invariant in my sets, since they consist of sets of keys/handles, which may very often partially overlap. Btw, I have searched on stackoverflow, google and wiki, but I could find what exactly you mean by NamedSet. Could you please explain?

Comment: NamedSet is just something I made up :-) so you can say mySet.getType() or mySet.getName() on the assumption that there is some common relationship that describes the elements in the set.

Comment: ah! ok, I see. Yes, this maybe indeed an option, since the keySet is the result of some query. Maybe somehow I could use the query as key.. of course.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this potentially a slow process? When is it calculated?
>   As soon as the Set is generated or on demand?
>   Couldn't this actually eat up lots the performance gains I expect to gain by caching?

In principle, this is not specified in the Set interface, thus it depends on the implementation.

For the general-purpose Set implementations in `java.util` and `java.util.concurrent` (as well as the set views of the general purpose maps), `hashCode()` is calculated on demand, and **will be slow for bigger sets**. (For small sets with simple elements, this does not really matter.)

The reason is that the `hashCode` (as well as `equals`) as defined is dynamic, e.g. changes whenever an element is added or removed, and changes also if the hashCode of an element changes (which is problematic by itself for hash-based sets). Thus, normally a Set/List/Map is not really a good key for a map.

For an immutable set (which is also in practice the only type of set which is really suitable as a map key), the hash code could be calculated once (either on creation or on the first use) and then cached (like String does it).

One could also implement such a caching for mutable sets, as long as the hash codes of the elements don't change: The formula is simple enough that it is possible to update the value on every addition or removal without inspecting anything than the added/removed element. But make sure the set does not change while it is used as a key in a map.

(Most of this also applies to List and Map with their similar `hashCode()` formulas.)

Comment: thank you, Paulo. Basically you confirm my concerns, that this is a bit problematic. My Set is final, so the approach should be ok, but it would create a general overhead, I'm trying to figure out how to avoid.